# Can I access an emmc card on android wear through usb?

Tags: android, window, usb, wear-os

I would like to know if there is a way to access an android wear sdcard from a windows computer, to put or retrieve a file via usb. The card on the watch is a emmc card.
Of course without using ADB, I want to access it the same way I can access the sdcard of my phone.

Thank you in advance.